# How to render Dynamic of list (`Dynamics t [a]`)?

Tags: haskell, reflex, reflex-dom

I can draw element for `Dynamic t Item` but don't know how to draw element of `Dynamic t [Item]`

```
import Reflex.Dom

data ItemType
  = Apple
  | Banana
 deriving (Eq, Show)

-- In the real-world, this function build complex DOM. Oversimplified here for MCVE
-- 
itemElDyn :: MonadWidget t m => Dynamic t ItemType -> m ()
itemElDyn = display

type Items = [ItemType]

-- listItemElDyn :: MonadWidget t m => Dynamic t Items -> m ()
-- listItemElDyn = mapM_ display . sequenceA

-- listItemElDyn lsDyn = do
--   let dynList = sequenceA lsDyn
--   mapM_ display dynList

main :: IO ()
main = mainWidget $ itemElDyn (constDyn Apple)
```

Checking the type in `ghci` seem like a valid combination

````
```λ> :t mapM_ display . sequence $ constDyn [Apple,Banana]                       
mapM_ display . sequence $ constDyn [Apple,Banana]
  :: (PostBuild t m, DomBuilder t m, Traversable (Dynamic t)) => m ()
*Main
λ> :t mapM_ display . sequenceA $ constDyn [Apple,Banana]
mapM_ display . sequenceA $ constDyn [Apple,Banana]
  :: (PostBuild t m, DomBuilder t m, Traversable (Dynamic t)) => m ()
````

but got error when try to run

```
λ> mapM_ display . sequence $ constDyn [Apple,Banana]

<interactive>:72:1: error:
    • No instance for (Traversable (Dynamic t0))
        arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: How about just `display (constDyn [Apple,Banana])` ?

Comment: @luqui Sorry, that not what exactly what I want, maybe my code is too minimal. The real problem is I already have complex version of display single item and I want to repeatedly apply them for each of element in the list.

Comment: In that case I would go look at how `display` is implemented for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

What about `mconcat`? Something like (untested):

```
main = mainWidget $ display itemsDyn
  where
    itemsDyn = mconcat $ fmap (itemElDyn . constDyn) [Apple,Banana]
```

(Have you seen https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex/blob/develop/Quickref.md?)